# Как получить цену только что выбранного товара в woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php

Очень прошу о помощи!

Неделю бьюсь над проблемой, облазил сеть, писал на форум, решения нет.

Есть страница, на которой по клику на кнопку всплывает окно с простыми товарами, после выбора товара и клику по "Добавить в корзину" вспл окно закрывается. Проблема в том, чтобы получить цену только что выбранного товара, (потому что ее надо отобразить на этой странице, и добавить в калькулятор на этой же странице).
На этой же странице есть второе всплывающее окно, но с вариативными товарами. Задача там такая же.

Если в value вывожу

```html
<?php get_price_html(); ?>
```

, ломается страница.

Нашел функцию

```html
function add_price_widget()
{
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
$thePrice = $product->get_price(); //will give raw price
echo $thePrice;
}
```

На странице любого товара она прекрасно работает и выводит цену и в произвольном месте, и в value, а на моей странице, где товары еще не выбраны и функция не имеет значений переменных, ошибка, пробовал и в пустом месте страницы, и в value - без разницы, ошибка -

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on boolean in /var/www/.../twentysixteen/functions.php:611

Строка 611 - $thePrice = $product->get_price();

Писали на другом форуме, что без перезагрузки страницы только через js.

Помогите, пожалуйста. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Если тип данных `boolean`, то вполне вероятно там `false`, а значит перед использованием нужно проверить: `$thePrice = $product ? $product->get_price() : 0;` (псевдокод).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! А не могли бы вы еще подсказать, куда  эту строку поместить?  В функцию перед строкой 611? Спасибо.

Comment: Вместо того, что на строке 611, т.е. заменить.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да, ошибка пропала, на странице вывелось "0".  Но при клике на "добавить в корзину" товара 0 так и остается, цена этого товара не выводится